# How to create a Visual force page from apex Class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've created a apex class in which I used current page name for some purpose.Now while creating a Test class for that I need to create a virtual visual Force page.So how to create that page in test class.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get the page reference using -

```
PageReference vfPageRef= Page.vfPageName;
```

and set current PageReference for the controller. -

```
Test.setCurrentPage(vfPageRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the current page ref as the page you are testing.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.success; 
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to write your test code on current page? set current page using following code..

```
public static testMethod void testMyController()
 {      

PageReference pageRef = Page.YourPageName;

Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

/* Your code for test coverage */

}
```